# Error installing ipdb using Macports

Tags: python, macports, ipdb

I would like to install ipdb in Mac running Yosemite. When I type this:

```
sudo port install ipdb.
```

It gives me this error:

```
Error: Port ipdb not found
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Macports? Most people have moved to Homebrew http://brew.sh/

Comment: Also, you should be able to install ipdb using pip: `pip install ipdb`

Comment: have been using macports a while. All my packages are downloaded via macports. That's why.

Comment: Fair enough, carry on

Comment: Please follow this tutorial when installing Python packages https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#virtual-environments

Comment: this is for virtualenv and pip. I am looking for Macports version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search the [MacPorts available ports list](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=ipdb) for `ipdb`, you'll find that there are several there, one for each MacPorts supported version of Python.  Be aware that the MacPorts projects is deprecating older versions of Python so you should choose either the Python 2.7 or 3.4 version.  For example:

```
sudo port install py34-ipdb
```

You could also use the command line interface to search:

```
$ port search ipdb
ipdb_select @0.3_1 (python)
    common files for selecting default ipdb version

py-ipdb @0.8 (python)
    An enhanced Interactive Python shell

py24-ipdb @0.8_1 (python)
    this port is only a stub and has been made obsolete by py27-ipdb

py25-ipdb @0.8_1 (python)
    this port is only a stub and has been made obsolete by py27-ipdb

py26-ipdb @0.8_1 (python)
    this port is only a stub and has been made obsolete by py27-ipdb

py27-ipdb @0.8 (python)
    An enhanced Interactive Python shell

py31-ipdb @0.8_1 (python)
    this port is only a stub and has been made obsolete by py34-ipdb

py32-ipdb @0.8_1 (python)
    this port is only a stub and has been made obsolete by py34-ipdb

py33-ipdb @0.8_1 (python)
    this port is only a stub and has been made obsolete by py34-ipdb

py34-ipdb @0.8 (python)
    An enhanced Interactive Python shell

Found 10 ports.
```